# Is there some resourses where I can sell pc time for mining?

Tags: mining-pools, cloud-mining

is there some resourses where I can sell pc time for mining. I'm not talking about project where people set "some software" on pc and recive 1$ per day, that was popular on time low cost mining of bitcoin and where people even don't know that they mine bitcoins. I`m talking of market where people fully understand what they do. I know about cex.io, but there you buy and sell power of hoster, not your personal calculating power. The only place what I found is ebay, where from time to time people sell their calculate power for hours or days. Anything similar?

Comment: Are you talking about mining *Bitcoin* or another currency?

Comment: Not only bitcoin.

Answer (score 1):

A PC's general purpose CPU is so far outclassed by specialized mining chips (ASIC's) that its value for mining is almost null. Perhaps the only instance where a PC could be useful for mining is at the very beginning of a crypto-currencies life cycle, when has just been launched, and very few are mining it. But when ASIC mining hardware joins the coin's network, difficulty will rise and render CPU miners inconsequential.
If you expand the definition of PC to include ASIC mining hardware, then the idea of selling hash power is interesting though. I found the following reference to this idea: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Hash_Market

Comment: I ran some calculations and found that running an average (4MHash/s) PC for 24 hours gives you slightly better odds of mining a block than winning the Powerball lottery with a single ticket.. Save some money(in electricity) and buy a lotto ticket instead.

Comment: Goes to show how low the odds of winning the lotto are... I read that the chance getting into a car accident while driving a few miles to buy a ticket for the MegaMillions, is about 8 times greater than hitting the jackpot. So, I guess you've got a good point. If one does not mind the electricity cost, CPU mining is a good lottery to play ... http://www.durangobill.com/MegaMillionsOdds.html

Comment: Yea, personally I think it's worth it /in the winter/..  because the electricity isn't wasted, it just turns into heat, which makes me heater run less. Really makes me look at computing as a zero-cost activity heh

Comment: Yes, I know about CPU mining and current situation, there are too many advisers that try to look forward for me, but not answer question. Dan K seems like there was such idea, but adress didn`t work now. May be you know why?